# How to remove the seconds from timeValue function

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking to print out the time 6:00am without the seconds. Using TimeValue it includes the seconds. Is there away to do this without including the seconds?

```
  CurrentTime = TimeValue("6:00 am")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use built-in [FormatDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with `vbShortTime` :

```
CurrentTime = FormatDateTime("6:00:31 am", vbShortTime)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a RegExp to zap the offending seconds from the **string** representation of the date:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = ":\d\d "
>> dtCurrentTime = TimeValue("6:00 PM")
>> sCurrentTime = CStr(dtCurrentTime)
>> sCurrentTime = r.Replace(sCurrentTime, " ")
>> WScript.Echo qq(sCurrentTime)
>>
"6:00 PM"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dtCurrentTime = TimeValue("6:00 PM")
sCurrentTime = CStr(dtCurrentTime)
sCurrentTime=Replace (sCurrentTime,":00:00 PM",":00 PM")
MsgBox sCurrentTime
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But I use Mid, Left & Right functions to solve it.

```
ThisTime = TimeValue(YourTime)

TimeSpace = InStr(1,ThisTime," ")

ThisShortTime = Left(ThisTime,TimeSpace-4) & Right(ThisTime,3)
```

`InStr` looks for the space within the time.

`Left` picks up the left side of the time, minus the second.

`Right` picks up the last 3 characters of the time, eg " AM" or " PM".